# calculate integral of given function

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

let us consider following integral

[image]

while if we calculate  from -infinity to plus infinity then  it says that

[image]

generally it should be 1/infinity +1/infinity right? which should be equal to zero,then why does it says that integral does not converge?

Comment: You're overlooking the singularity at $0$.

Comment: What happens in zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no primitive of $-\frac1{t^2}$ on all of $\mathbb R$. $\frac1t$ is a primitive of $-\frac1{t^2}$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and on $(0,\infty)$, but not on $\mathbb R$. Thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty -\frac1{t^2}\ \mathrm dt \ne \frac1{\infty} - \frac1{-\infty}$$
Looking more closely and using symmetry you can see that actually
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty -\frac1{t^2}\ \mathrm dt = 2\int_0^\infty -\frac1{t^2} \ \mathrm dt = -\infty$$
Where the last integral can be "evaluated" to $-\infty$ by using the primitive on $(0,\infty)$.

A similar thing happens to $\int \frac1t\ \mathrm dt$ with primitive $\ln |t|$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$. Here you can see that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac1t\ \mathrm dt$ is actually undefined although $[\ln |t|]_{-1}^1 = 0$.

Comment: could you tell me please one integrate function?thanks for answer

Comment: @datodatuashvili I'm sorry but I can't grammatically understand your comment.

Comment: sorry i mean  function integral of which exist  from -infinity to plus infinity

Comment: How about$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \ \mathrm dx = \sqrt\pi\quad?$$

Comment: nice  thank you i need to use   such function for Poisson sumation

Comment: how can i do the same code in excel?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Wich code? This seems to be an entirely different question. Maybe you should ask a new one somewhere (questions about Excel aren't on-topic here usually). Do you need any further clarification regarding the present question? If not, please mark it as answered. If so, feel free to ask.